# Is it possible to make changes in all databases on server at once?

Tags: php, mysql, database, server

I have a website where there are almost 20 databases. They all have some tables in common. If I have to make any change, I have to make it in table of every database one by one. I have root level access of the server. Is there any way or any php script so that I can make change in the table of each database at once?

Comment: Write your own script. It shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code with what you've tried and what's failed.

Answer (score 2):

Something like a loop over different database names?

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=...", "myuser", "mypassword");

$databases = ["db1", "db2", "db3"]; // as many as you need
$pdo->beginTransaction();
for ($databases as $dbname) {
  $sql = "UPDATE {$dbname}.mytable SET column1 = 'something'";
  $pdo->exec($query);
}
$pdo->commit();
```

Of course this has several placeholder values that you would have to fill in with values specific for your project.